# what is the difference in displaying data in c++ using insertion(<<) operator and "write" function?

Tags: c++, operators, ostream

I found both do the same for the output

1- insertion (<<) operator

```
cout<<"ahmed";
```

2- using the function write of the object cout from class ostream

```
cout.writr("ahmed" , 5);
```

but I don't know if there is a hidden difference that I can't realize

can some one answer me in this ?

thanks in advance

Comment: The `<<` operator will format the output as text. Doesn't have to do much if it *already is* text. It will be quite different if you output an `int` or a `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- insertion (<<) operator will print until it meet '\0'.

2- using the function write of the object cout from class ostream will print enough char, even it meet '\0' or beyond the boundary.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    const char *str1="abc\0def";
    const char *str2="ghi";
    cout<<str1<<endl;
    cout<<"------------\n";
    cout.write(str1,7);
    cout<<"\n------------\n";
    cout.write(str1,7+3);
}


result:
abc
------------
abcdef
------------
abcdefgh
```

Comment: Does "write" function print "gh" as extra from str2 because they are neighbored in the memory ? And if it didn't find any neighbors does it will put garpage ?

Comment: yes, they are neighbored in the memory. If you don't initialize the neighbored, you will get garpage .